# csv parsing data thru to high charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to parse a csv file into a lazy high charts graph.

I have used paperclip to upload the csv file, and I am having issues parsing the data and i'm not really sure how to do it.

The csv file has 3 columns. Columns 2 and 3 are the ones i wish to access. column 2 is dates and 3 is temperatures.

Controller

```
   def show
    @soiltemp = Soiltemp.find(params[:id])
    @data = CSV.parse(@soiltemp.csv.path, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
    dates = []
    temps = []
    @data.each do |row|
    dates << row[1]
    temps << row[2]
        end
    @graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.title({ :text=>"Combination chart"})
      f.options[:xAxis][:categories] = dates
      f.series(:type=> 'area', :name=> 'Degree', :data => [temps], :color => '#00463f')  
    end
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@soiltemps) do |soiltemps, marker|
      marker.lat soiltemps.latitude
      marker.lng soiltemps.longitude
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: 'soiltemps/map')
    end
```

View

```
<%= high_chart("chart", @graph) %>
<p><b>Last Updated:</b> <%= @soiltemp.updated_at.strftime("%d %B, %Y") %></p>

<%= link_to 'Back', soiltemps_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need arrays of values from each column to give to your high charts `series`. You would go through each row of csv data (`@data.each`) and each row within the block is itself an array of the value in each column of the csv but 0 indexed. So to get column 2 you'd ask for `row[1]`.

Here's what you could do:

```
def show
    @soiltemp = Soiltemp.find(params[:id])
    @data = CSV.parse(@soiltemp.csv.path, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')

    dates = []
    temperatures = []

    @data.each do |row|
      dates << row[1] # column 2
      temperatures << row[2] # column 3
    end

    @graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.title({ :text=>"Combination chart"})
      # make the csv row headers the graph's categories
      f.options[:xAxis][:categories] = @data.headers
      f.series(:data => dates, ...rest of options)  
      f.series(:data => temperatures, ...rest of options)
    end
    ... rest of code ...
end
```

Which array (dates or temps) you give to which series is up to you. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering Diego. I have updated y controller to reflect what i am trying to attain, but I am getting a blank graph, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Ok, I have the dates showing, but the f.series(:data => temps) will not show.